# have to or will have to?

Tags: present-tense, future-constructions

Should "have" and "don't' be changed to "will have" and "won't" in the following?

> Josh, my coworkers and I will put on a play at 4 p.m. this weekend.  Will you come?

> Sorry, I **have** to work.  I **don’t** have time.

Answer (score 1):

No. In English it is very common to use the present tense to refer to an activity that will actually happen in the future.

You can think of it as meaning:

> Sorry, I have to work [at that time]. I don't have the time [then].

I might use "won't" instead of "don't," but definitely not "will have" instead of "have."

Answer (score 0):

> Josh, my coworkers and I will put on a play at 4 p.m. this weekend. Will you come?

I would suggest that in this situation you should be using **Future Continuous not Future Simple** as a play will be on-going.

> Josh, my coworkers and I will be putting on a play at 4 p.m. this weekend. Will you be coming?

Also, the **replies,** I would suggest are **incorrect**. "Sorry, I have to work. I don’t have time" As stand alone sentences, they work however together they do not sound correct. Why, because it is obvious that the first phrase "*I have to work"* is relating to the period of time talked about in the question but the the second phrase is relating to the first phrase, the fact you will be working. Therefore the reply would be

> ***"Sorry, I have to work and will not have time".***

> Sorry, I have to work.

> Sorry, I don’t have time.

Comment: Your answer badly needs better punctuation.  Note that there is a difference in meaning between:: **Also the replies I would suggest are incorrect.** and **Also, the replies, I would suggest, are incorrect.**

Comment: @Ronald Sole. Thank you.